# Avoid setting of same Alarm again and again

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

In my android app, I have two services which are supposed to run timely.
One will run on a fixed date and the other will run on 11:00 PM everyday.

To achieve this, I have created services and used Alarm manager to start them at fixed time.

```
private void scheduleAlarmForCleanup(){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);


        Intent pendingIntent = new Intent(this, CleanupService.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, pendingIntent, 0);


        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000 , pintent);
    }
```

Now I have called this function in my Activity's onCreate.
But onCreate can be called multiple times during a day
and my concern is this will lead to multiple calls to this function.

What effect can this have ?
Would the Alarm be set multiple times.
Is there a way by which I can check whether my alarm is already set and in that case I won't try to set alarm again.

Answer (score 0):

Each time, you will have to try to cancel the alarm and set it again.

```
try
{
    // This block will cancel the alarm if already available. Else throw an 
    // exception which will be ignored
    alarmManager.cancel(pintent);
}catch (Exception ignored){ }

// After try block, set the manager again.
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000 , pintent);
```